# Missing Template while running Cron Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

There is a strange issue we are facing in our  **Rails** application while we are running cron jobs. Our cron jobs are running successfully, however after that it is resulting in the "Missing Template" error. Unless we sort this out, the testing team will not allow to pass this through, so kindly help!!

Providing the code snippet and flow.

**/etc/crontab**

```
 55 5    * * *   user  sh /root_path/config/cron/shell_commands/environment/test.sh
```

**test.sh**

```
wget http://localhost:3000/cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks/test/key
```

**cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks.rb**

```
class CronJobs::ExecuteCronTasksController < ApplicationController
   def test
     CronTasks.test_cron if params[:key] && params[:key] == "key"
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html {render :status => Rack::Utils.status_code(:ok)}
       format.js {render :status => Rack::Utils.status_code(:ok)}
     end
   end
end
```

**module cron_tasks.rb**

```
module CronTasks
  def self.test_cron
    puts "=======================working===========================".red
  end
end
```

After calling the cron job it will print the data but throwing an 500 Internal Server Error

**Server log**

```
Started GET "/cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks/test/getmeinfirst" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-19 15:27:13 +0530
Processing by CronJobs::ExecuteCronTasksController#test as */*
Parameters: {"key"=>"key"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks/test, application/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "/root_path/app/views"
* "/root_path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-1.4.2/app/views"
):

 app/controllers/cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks_controller.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in test'
 app/controllers/cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks_controller.rb:82:in `test'


  Rendered /root_path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.3ms)
```

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you don't want to render anything in the body. In that case, try

```
format.html {render :status => Rack::Utils.status_code(:ok), :nothing => true}
```

If you do want to render a view, you probabily should put it in:

```
app/views/cron_jobs/execute_cron_tasks/test.html.erb
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replaying. It is working fine now,But a small issue is there. It is creating a file in the name of "key" which I am passing with the request in the root folder. Can you please tell what is the issue.